# cURL works but axios.get doesn't

Tags: node.js, curl, axios

This seems a popular genre of question but I haven't been able to find the answer elsewhere. I have a Node.JS script as follows:

```
const axios_1 = require("axios");                                                                    
const dataUrl = "https://maps.amtrak.com/services/MapDataService/trains/getTrainsData";              
console.log("getting");                                                                              
axios_1.get(dataUrl).then(                                                                           
  (data) => {console.log(data);}                                                                     
)                                                                                                    
.catch((err) => {console.log(err);});
```

I get a 403 on the `axios` GET above, but if I do `curl https://maps.amtrak.com/services/MapDataService/trains/getTrainsData` I get data. Any ideas on what I should look for to fix the problem?

Comment: What version of Axios are you using?

Comment: The target is notoriously badly engineered. That is _exactly_ (!) my `curl` command! No credentials and none needed.

Comment: Is this the only use of Axios in your application? Have you added any default headers or interceptors anywhere else?

Comment: I don't know which version! `package-lock.json` says 0.25.0 - is that the right place to look?

Comment: Yep, cheers. That's pretty old but also probably stable (don't get me started on any version over 1.0.0)

Comment: The problem replicates with this minimal code. This is actually coming in from a library but I don't use Axios anywhere else.

Comment: Seems to be an issue with the underlying Node `https` module. I could reproduce the issue on Node v16 but it's not present in v18

Comment: Dump Axios. Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74594513/4797603 You might not need any auth and if that's the case just delete that part. Node.js does GET out of the box.

Comment: @RonnieRoyston Axios is just a wrapper for `http` / `https` in Node. If the issue is with the Node version then dumping Axios won't achieve anything.

Comment: @Phil OK but the problem here is not Node.js, is it? The API call isn't scripted correctly. I find that the Axios/node-fetch/Got libraries to be unnecessary, that's all. It's probably `rejectUnauthorized: false,` that he needs to add.

Comment: @RonnieRoyston you must have missed my comment where I said it works in Node v18

Comment: @Phil I upgraded to 18.12 and weirdly axios now just *hangs* - the promise never resolves - but at least it's a new pathology :) Ronnie, thank you - I'd prefer to use axios for simplicity but your solution does work!

Comment: You got it working using vanilla Node.js. What could be more simple than that! :-)

Comment: I had a similar issue with axios (version 1.4.0) where curl was working but axios not responding/hanging. This turned out to be a problem with the `Connection: close` header that axios was sending on a request (tcpdump and switching to http helped figure).  Setting axios.defaults.headers.common['Connection'] = 'keep-alive' removes the connection header as a part of the request and mimicked the curl. Possibly with the upstream having an issue with persistent connections

Answer (score 3):

Seems to work in Node v18 (but not v16) using the following...

```js
axios.get(dataUrl, {
  headers: {
    accept: '*/*',
    'user-agent': 'curl/7.79.1',
  },
  timeout: 5000, // it has a habit of timing out
});
```

This at least uses the exact same headers as `curl` and it seems to work reasonably consistently.

I haven't bothered to set up a Wireshark SSL proxy to really inspect the differences but might do over the weekend because this is somewhat fascinating.

Comment: Weird. On my set-up, curl still works but Axios times out! If you do get any results from inspecting via proxy I'd be fascinated to hear. I'm a little too green to be able to set that up efficiently myself.

Comment: Had a similar issue with node 16, later updated to 18+ now works fine, it was tough to know why this was happening.